# Centering an Aligning a Derivation

Tags: align, center

I am trying to center and align a derivation. When I am in the rich text format, I get the following[image]

However, when I compile the pdf I get the following:
[image]

I am not sure how to fix this. Here is my Latex Code. Please help:

```
      \begin{center}
      \begin{align*}
      \mathbb{E}(\hat{f}(x_i) - f(x_i)) &= \int K(y)\bigg( f(x_i) - hyf'(x_i) + \frac{1}{2}h^2y^2f''(x_i) + O(h^2)\bigg) dy - f(x_i)\\
      &= f(x_i)\int K(y)dy + hf'(x_i)\int yK(y)dy + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0)\int y^2K(y)dy +O(h^2) - f(x_i)\\
      &= f(x_i)\big( 1\big) +  hf'(x_i) \big( 0\big) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0)\int y^2K(y)dy +O(h^2) - f(x_i)\\
      &= 1/2 h^2f''(x_0)\int y^2K(y)dy +O(h^2) \\
      \end{align*}
      \end{center}
```

Comment: The `center` environment around `align*` is superfluous and you can eliminate it. But your code compiles fine for me. I suspect that you have a blank line in your code after `\begin{align*}`, which would yield the output you observe.

Comment: (i) please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document which we can compile and which reproduce your problem, (ii) your code fragment used in standard `article` document class doesn't reproduce your problem. I wonder, why you enclose your equations into `center` environment?

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot you posted would appear to be based on a `gather*` environment. However, your code employs an `align*` environment, with `=` set as the alignment point in all four rows. For the equation at hand, I think it's preferable to align the rows on the `=` symbols than to simply center them.

Some suggestions:

- Never encase a display math environment -- such as `align*` -- in a `center` environment. Why? Because they are centered horizontally by default.
- The `\bigg(` and `\bigg)` directives in the first row create preposterously large parentheses. I'd use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`.
- I'd also replace all instances of `\frac{1}{2} with` \tfrac{1}{2}`. There's no need to give a lot of visual prominence to these fraction terms.
- Insert `\,` (thinspace) between the integrands and the `dy` terms.
- I can see no valid typographic reason for enlarging the parentheses around the `0` and `1` terms in row 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\bigl(\hat{f}(x_i) - f(x_i)\bigr) 
&= \int\! K(y)\bigl[ f(x_i) - hyf'(x_i) + \tfrac{1}{2}h^2y^2f''(x_i) + O(h^2)\bigr]\,dy - f(x_i)\\
&= f(x_i)\int\! K(y)\,dy + hf'(x_i)\int\! yK(y)\,dy + \tfrac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0)\int\! y^2K(y)\,dy + O(h^2) - f(x_i)\\
&= f(x_i)(1) +  hf'(x_i) (0) + \tfrac{1}{2}h^2f''(x_0)\int\! y^2K(y)\,dy +O(h^2) - f(x_i)\\
&= \tfrac{1}{2} h^2f''(x_0)\int\! y^2K(y)\,dy +O(h^2) \,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I of course agree with your suggestions, but I think the diagnosis is what I said in my comment. Look closely to the picture in the question: many letters are in text mode. You get exactly that result with a blank line; the `center` environment does the rest.

Comment: @campa - I will admit to not being confident about *how* the four lines in the OP's screenshot were generated. Judging by the small size of the integral symbols, my *hunch* is that the OP  used a `center` environment (just like you're guessing) and then had LaTeX process the math in (forced) inline-math mode. The OP must received a ton of error and warning messages.in the process.